# How impartial is medical research?

Tags: research

This question comes off the back of an answer to [this question](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/16562/7604) where there was reference to a retraction of an article in The Lancet based on inaccuracies and fraudulent data.

As a lot of research (if not all) are funded by interested parties such as pharmaceutical companies, the legal profession, etc. I was wondering if there are any articles released which has results in opposite to the best interest of the funding organisation(s)?

[One example I have recently found by chance within the fields of Psychology and Neuroscience](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/26642/7604) involves using Vagus Nerve Stimulation (VNS) to treat difficult-to-treat depression (DTD).  Due to the amount of research with conflicts of interest concerning manufacturer(s) of VNS equipment, it is hard if not impossible to find any research completely free of the possible influence the manufacturer(s) have had so far.

Here I am looking for any examples which will show that there is medical research which is completely impartial and not necessarily just the example here.

Comment: This means the whole system is corrupted.  Including scientific researches..We already lost faith in Media... then Judiciary.. now its researches :(

Comment: Not necessarily @Fghj - OK there was this one incident of an article retraction but it shows that there are checks.

Comment: But there are some chances. 10-20%

Comment: @Fghj - Nothing is ideal. The media, governments, banks, science - none have a spotless reputation. You can find dark deeds in any of their histories. But it doesn't mean that all or even most things that they do are bad. There are also many good deeds done by them. And I think that overall the systems are improving and the ratio of bad deeds to good deeds is declining.